# How many ways can blocks be arranged in a grid

Tags: geometry, sorting, multigrid

I have a 16x16 grid to fill up with 4 different sized blocks listed below:

16x16
16x8
8x16
8x8

How many different combinations of 16x16 grids can I make while filing the grid up completely?

Just to clarify the rules a little bit, I can use multiple instances of the same block like this image below shows:

[Grid filled with 4 8x8 blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiRS0.png)

I can also use mixed typed of blocks in any order like this:

[Mixed Block Variation 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieoRK.png)

[Mixed Block Variation 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jY10.png)

I have searched online for algorithms related to my question, but the best I could find were permutations that show many ways you could re-arrange a set of numbers.

I worked out by hand a small sample set of a 2x2 grid and 2 block sizes (1x2 and 1x1), but the result wasn't the same as the number of permutations, because I could make 3 different types of grids while the number of permutations was only 2. (See the 3 examples below):

[Fully worked 2x2 grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwVtp.png)

I also found this [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923331/how-many-different-ways-can-the-numbers-1-9-be-arranged-in-a-3x9-grid), but the question adheres to a different set of rules than what I am trying to follow as I have no concerns about containing duplicates of blocks in any part of the grid, just that the grid is completely filled up.

Comment: Are you interested in generalising this? Or only in the specific case? You'll make things much easier for yourself by noticing that you're only really filling a $2\times 2$ grid with blocks of size $2\times 2$, $2\times 1$, $1\times 2$ and $1\times 1$

Comment: If you're not trying to generalize, just count the ways exhaustively. There's one way using the big square, one way using four small squares, two ways using two rectangles, and four ways using one rectangle and two small squares. $1+1+2+4=8$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

I would define the counting sequence from largest pieces downwards:

- what's the largest piece? 16x16
- does it fill the space? Yes. **1** counted
- are there similar configurations? No

We then repeat this algorithm until we've run through all pieces. This cycle gives 3 for 16x8 (16x8+16x8, 16x8+8x8+8x8, 8x8+8x8+16x8.) another 3 for the 8x16 piece, and 1 for the 8x8.

So we have 8 configurations (without counting flipped or rotated variations.)

For larger sets, notice how once we block off some of the area with our current largest piece, we perform the algorithm internally. This guarantees the coverage of all states. This method of working downwards generalizes to any set of objects in any space.

Comment: I understand your idea of counting down from the largest block, but I'm a little confused when you said "We have 8 configurations (without counting flipped or rotated variations)". Didn't you include a flipped variation when you counted to 3 using the 16x8? What's the difference between 16x8 + 8x8 + 8x8 and 8x8 + 8x8 + 16x8 if it's not flipped?

Comment: Are you saying I can count down from the largest block to the smallest going in a single direction, and then multiply that number by 4, for every variation containing multiple blocks in order to account for flipped/rotated variations?

Comment: Flipping individual pieces not symmetrical overall set ups

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still a little bit confused. What do you mean by flipping individual pieces that are not symmetrical. Do you mean calculate only symmetrical configurations, and then test each configuration for a symmetrical counterpart to add to the total number?